# Django how to hide ID from URL

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-urls

I'm using Django.

I want to hide Id from URL.

url:

```
path('<int:news_pk>/', views.newsDetailView, name='detail'),
```

View:

```
def newsDetailView(request, news_pk):
    news = get_object_or_404(News, id=news_pk)
 
    return render(request, "news/pages/index-inner.html", {
        'news': news,
    })
```

Model:

```
class News(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='title') 
                               verbose_name='snippet')  
    content = RichTextUploadingField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='content')
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "news"
        verbose_name_plural = verbose_name

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Any friend can help?

Comment: Have you looked into a unique SlugField? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#slugfield

Comment: use unique SlugField it will help you